# Excluding a specific category in a photo gallery

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with a Wp theme on a site and I am having a problem excluding categories from the photo gallery. This is the work in progress site. I am trying to exclude 2-3 categories from the catch all part of the photo gallery under the 'shop' nav. For example I want to exclude the colors from the shop but still allow them to show up under the 'colors' tab.

I am thinking it is somewhere in the bit of code below. I have been searching everywhere and tried a few things but I am not very savvy at php. Any insight would be awesome.

```
<?php
        //get portfolio categories
        $cats = get_terms('portfolio_cats');
        //show filter if categories exist
        if($cats[1] !='') { ?>

        <!-- Portfolio Filter -->
        <ul class="filter clearfix">
            <li class="sort"><?php _e('Sort Items','workz'); ?>:
            <li class="cat-item active"><a href="#all"><span><?php _e('All', 'workz'); ?></span></a>
            <?php
            foreach ($cats as $cat ) : ?>
            <li class="cat-item"><a>slug; ?>" class="<?php echo $cat->slug; ?>"><span><?php echo $cat->name; ?></span></a>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line :

```
<li class="cat-item"><a>slug; ?>" class="<?php echo $cat->slug; ?>"><span><?php echo $cat->name; ?></span></a>//error near <a> php tag incomplete
```

**To**

```
<li class="cat-item"><a href="#" class="<?php echo $cat->slug; ?>"><span><?php echo $cat->name; ?></span></a>
```

Comment: I have tried this code its working but still having issue with getting them connected with original post. Its redirecting it to homepage while clicking on link